# how to get selected options belongs to product

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder, laravel-queue

Thank you all in advance ,
i have peoject for ecommerce app

please check simplified DB schema for better unsrstand

products

```
- id
- name
- some other columns ...
```

product_items

```
- id
- product_id
- some other columns ...
```

options

```
- id
- name
```

option_values

```
- id
- option_id
- option_text
```

when admin add new product with options we have to add new row in product_items tabel and related options in product_item_options

product_item_values

```
- product_item_id
- option_value_id
```

now in need to acsess product with related options , and product with oprions and option values

option_values

| product_item_id | option_value_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |

etc..

```
product {
id : 1,
name : foo bar,
options : {
[
id: 1,
name : cpu
],[
id:2,
name : ran
]
}
}
```

```
product_item {
id : 1,
name : foo bar,
options : {
[
id: 1,
name : cpu,
values: {
[id: 1], [id:3]
}
],[
id:2,
name : ran,
values: {
[id: 2], [id:3]
}
]
}
}
```

i have tried to get

```
    App\Models\productItem
    
    public function options(): HasManyThrough
    {
      return $this->belongsToMany(OptionValue::class);
    }
```

this relation return option values . but how how to acsess options with values from App\Models\Product

i hope i can clear the situation

Edit 1 :

```
App\Models\Product
```

```
    public function items(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductItem::class);
    }
```

```
App\Models\Options
```

```
    public function values()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(OptionsValue::class);
    }
```

```
App\Models\OptionsValue
```

```
    public function Option() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Option::class);
    }
```

Edit 2 :

1- `Product` have 1 or more items

2- `Product Item` belong to one `Product`

3- `option` have one or more values

4- `Product Item` have 0 or more options

Comment: You've spelt `options` wrong in your ProductItem model. Is that a typo?

Comment: Also, you've not included any of your relationships. Can a product have multiple product items? Can product items belong to many products?

Comment: @Super_Simon Thanks you , yes options is just typo , i have add all related relations

Comment: I'm still not fully understanding this. So `Product Item` is not related to `Option` at all? Should it be: `Product` has many `Product Items`, `Product Items` belongs to one `Product` and `Option` has many `Option Values` and `Option Values` belongs to one `Option`?

Comment: @Super_Simon yes this exsactly what the DB scehma now , but if selution to edit database or relations no problem , 
i can change anything , in final result i need to get `Product` with `Product items` with `options` with `option value`